# How to upload unity project to github

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello I been having this question for quite sometime in my head, I was wondering if someone may help me with it. My question is this. How can I upload a unity project like a game to github? Is it the same way as uploading a website to github?

Comment: It is, but you would like to configure your .gitignore file first. 
There are some examples on Internet, like this one; https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore

Comment: also please take a look on "git lfs" if your project has any image/model files

Answer (score 2):

If it's your first time uploading a Unity Game to Github I recommend using the [Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) application. I leave you here a very good tutorial so that you can carry out your goal. I hope it's useful!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpXxcvS-g3g